# Acces NMS present in intranet through internet

Tags: web-server, internet, intranet

I am having NMS application(OpenNMS) running in my intranet network at 172.16.3.32.I have developed an android application which call the webservices running on the NMS machine.I have successfully tested this in my emulator from my p.c.Now i am planning to test the same app from a real device. So i think my existing NMS should be accessed through internet. How could i achieve this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a reverse proxy server in a DMZ to proxy the request back to your NMS server, putting a cheap SSL certificate on the proxy server is a very good idea too if you send login details in the web request. 
Apache HTTPd for example can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your router model and follow the guide on [portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm) to forward port 80 to 172.16.3.32. Take a look at [dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/) or [no-ip](http://www.no-ip.com/) if you are using dynamic IP.